# How do you know if a code signing certificate for a file is ok?

Tags: security, certificate, authentication, digital-signature, code-signing

Which things should you look out for, to indicate all looks okay, when viewing a downloaded file's "Digital Signatures" tab in Windows 10?

What are the signs there may be an issue with the file or it's certificate?
E.g. file is a fake or has been tampered with, fake or stolen certificate.

What would make a weak or strong code signing certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the main question, select each signature in the *Signature list* of the *Digital Signatures* tab, then press **Details**.  If you see `This digital signature is OK` listed at the top of the General tab (for each signature), then the file can be deemed 'trustworthy' and untampered with, [as illustrated here](https://support.datalocker.com/support/solutions/articles/4000133391-how-to-verify-a-digital-code-signing-signature-in-windows).

If a file is corrupt, modified after signing, then the Digital Signature should disappear from the file completely.  If not, or the file contains an untrusted, expired, or invalid digital signature, then the *Digital Signature Details* dialog will contain a corresponding message, other than `This digital signature is OK`

Various code-signing certificate attributes (or lack thereof) can make a signature weak.  For example, these are considered weak or bad practice:

- Use of legacy (small) **Signature Hash Algorithm** (SHA) (eg, MD5, SHA1,    etc).
- Use of a small RSA **Public Key** (eg, less than 2048 bits).
- Not including a **Countersignature** from a trusted timestamping service.
- Lack of, or inappropriate **Key Usage** flags or **Enhanced Key Usage** OIDs.
- Not including **Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Distribution Points**,    and/or lack of **Authority Information Access On-line Certificate Status    Protocol (OCSP)** URLs to determine the validity of certs at time-of-use.

Microsoft offers several tools to check the validity of digital signatures on files.  For example, SysInternals `sigcheck.exe`, the `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` PowerShell cmdlet, `signtool.exe verify` offered in several MS SDKs or DDKs, etc.  If interested, see the various answers in [How to check if a file has a digital signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/667017/11609403)